# postgresql 9.1.3: "operator not unique" issues

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following query errors:

```
db=# select 'test' || 123;
ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown || integer
LINE 1: select 'test' || 123;
                      ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.

db=# select 'test'::text || 123;
ERROR:  operator is not unique: text || integer
LINE 1: select 'test'::text || 123;
                            ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Now, in PGAdmin, in my Casts node for the DB, I have 13 of them defined, one of which is:

```
CREATE CAST (integer AS text)
  WITH FUNCTION text(integer)
  AS IMPLICIT;
```

When we went to PG 9.1, I recreated implicit casts following the [method described here](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2008/03/readding-implicit-casts-in-postgresql.html).

I'm wondering if I have indeed created duplicate operators, and if so, how should I go about cleaning it up? If not, why am I getting this kind of error? It seems a rather straight forward cast.

Thanks!

Comment: select 'test' || 123; is not correct, you're trying to concat text and integer, select 'test'::text || 123; is not correct, you're trying to cast a text to text and then concat with integer, what you need to do is: select 'test' || 123::text; this works!

Comment: It's always a best practice to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried adding the same cast and it gives me the same error in 9.1.2.  I notice also the first comment on that blog (dated Feb 24 2009) reports this error.

This may have something to do with the following comment in the manual:

> Note: Before PostgreSQL 8.3, these functions would silently accept values of several non-string data types as well, due to the presence of implicit coercions from those data types to text. Those coercions have been removed because they frequently caused surprising behaviors. **However, the string concatenation operator (||) still accepts non-string input**, so long as at least one input is of a string type.

I think you are creating a duplicate operator by adding the implicit cast.  The integer could be cast to text and use `text || text` or not and use `text || integer`.  Looking in the tables I think the second may be `text || anynonarray` which can not be dropped.

In short the only way to fix this is use explicit casts when using the || operator **OR** drop the implicit cast you've created and use explicit casts every where else.

Comment: Is there anyway to drop the operator ||(text, anynonarray)? I just cannot put the explicit casts around hundreds of queries.

Comment: no.  I tied this, but its inbuilt and can't be changed or removed.

Answer (score 0):

faced same kind of issue where to solve one error i have to add those old implicit casting but that caused error somewhere else like - SELECT 1|| '/%'; query will throw error of not unique operator, i had to drop integer as text cast.